# Proof of Feynman-Kac theorem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am reading a proof of Feynman-Kac theorem as done [here](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/391/Lecture12.pdf), where I do not follow one step. Specifically, after the author derived:
$$dY_s = u_x(t-s, W_s)e^{-R(s)}dW_s$$
they seem to have concluded $$Y_t =u(0,W_t)e^{-R(t)}$$
in the next line. But the partial derivative in $x$ magically seemed to have disappeared.

Can anyone point out if this is a mistake or this is how it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot simpler than you thought. The definition of $Y_s$ is given in the beginning of the proof. He doesn't use the expression for $dY_s$ in any way in writing down $Y_t$.

At the beginning he defines $Y_s=e^{-R(s)}u(t-s,W_s)$. Letting $s=t$ gives $Y_t=e^{-R(t)}u(0,W_t)$.